# Passing the elements event using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to pass the elements "event" into a JavaScript function click using jQuery.

**INLINE:**
This is easy when doing it directly (inline).

```
<a href="#" onclick="ToggleMinimize('Hello World', event)">Click Me</a>
```

**USING JQUERY:**
But how do you do it using jQuery?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
    function ToggleMinimize(title, e) 
    {
        // ...various execution code would be here ... //
    }

    jQuery(window).load(function() {

        // How do I "get at" the "event" object for the element & pass it into the function definition?
        jQuery(".chatDialog-toggle-button").bind('click', ToggleMinimize);
    })
-->
</script>
```

Thanking you ahead of time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following on from what a lot of the other guys have shown regarding passing data to an event function, there is a specific method for this, you can pass a full object map this way per bind.

Also bare in mind that jQuery normalises the event object before you receive it, so it is a little different, see: http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/

```
function ToggleMinimize(e) {
    // ...various execution code would be here ... //
    // e.data contains the data object map
    // e.data.msg == "Hello World"
}

jQuery(window).load(function() {       
    jQuery(".chatDialog-toggle-button").bind('click', {'msg': "Hello World"}, ToggleMinimize);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to, it's already the first agument, like this:

```
function ToggleMinimize(e) {
    // ...various execution code would be here ... //
}
jQuery(window).load(function() {       
    jQuery(".chatDialog-toggle-button").bind('click', ToggleMinimize);
});
```

If you want to *also* pass a title, then use an anonymous function, like this:

```
function ToggleMinimize(title, e) {
  // ...various execution code would be here ... //
}
jQuery(window).load(function() {       
  jQuery(".chatDialog-toggle-button").click(function(e) {
    ToggleMinimize("some title", e);
  });
});
```

---

Personally I'd use a data attribute, like this:

```
<a href="#" class="chatDialog-toggle-button" data-title"Hello World">Click Me</a>
```

Then access it like this:

```
function ToggleMinimize(e) {
  var title = jQuery(this).data("title");
}
jQuery(window).load(function() {       
    jQuery(".chatDialog-toggle-button").click(ToggleMinimize);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can send an anonymous function which executs `ToggleMinimize()`:

```
jQuery(window).load(function() {
    jQuery(".chatDialog-toggle-button").bind('click', function(e) {
          ToggleMinimize( "Hello World", e);
    });
})
```

or you can have `ToggleMinimize` return a function, so you can pass `Hello World` into it.

```
function ToggleMinimize(title) {
    return function(e){ alert(title); alert(e.target); }
}

jQuery(window).load(function() {
    jQuery(".chatDialog-toggle-button").bind('click', ToggleMinimize( "Hello World") );
})
```

Comment: You guys are awesome!  I love this site!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.chatDialog-toggle-button').bind('click', function(event) {
      ToggleMinimize(event);
  });
});
```